# React Navigation Nested stack routeName

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to get the `routeName` of active route and show that in my header so I use:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  header: (
    <Header
      title={navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName}
    />
  )
})
```

Note that the `<Header>` is a custom component which I create.

The problem is I can't access the `routeName` in nested stacks!

```
TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]')
```

Any suggestion?

> Thanks in advance!

---

### UPDATE

My `Router.js`:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    _Landing: {
      screen: TabNavigator(
        {
          a: Splash,
          b: Splash,
          c: createStackNavigator(
            {
              d: Services,
              e: Splash
            },
            {
              initialRouteName: "d",
              navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({     // HERE is the problem
                header: (
                  <Header
                    title={
                      navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName
                    }
                  />
                )
              }),
              transitionConfig: getSlideFromRightTransition
            }
          ),
          f: Splash,
          g: Splash
        },
        {
          tabBarPosition: "bottom",
          initialRouteName: "c",
          animationEnabled: true,
          swipeEnabled: true,
          lazy: false
        }
      )
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "_Landing",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: (
        <Header
          title={navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName}
        />
      )
    }),
    transitionConfig: getSlideFromRightTransition
  }
);
```

Please note that the problem is in the `// Here is the problem` section. The Last `navigationOptions` is working!

Comment: Where you define `navigation`? `routeName` is undefined

Comment: this is my `Router.js` file and I use this `navigationOptions` in other `StackNavigator` - everything works! but in **nested stack** it's not working!

Comment: It is hard to guess what is causing the `navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]` to be undefined from the info you provided. Try and add some relevant info to the question, I would start by checking the index, then routes at index ....

Comment: I added the `Router.js` - Thanks